# Checking Process object error after start

Tags: c#, process, runtime-error

I have a method that create a Process object, sets paremeters and star it. Which way of checking the error is more correct in code below ?
this :

```
public void DoSomething(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

or this :

```
public void DoSomething(string command)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
        p.Start();
        string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest the first method, but its not a good technique to put all your line of code in the `try` block. Use `try` block only for the lines where exception is possible:

```
public void DoSomething(string command)
    {

        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
        try
        {
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading error should be after exit. You can try this below.

```
 process.WaitForExit();

 //Reading output and error
 string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 string strReturnValue = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Are you sure ? I find this in [msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.90).aspx) A deadlock condition can result if the parent process calls p.WaitForExit before p.StandardError.ReadToEnd and the child process writes enough text to fill the redirected stream